# How do I know the sending port number in QUdpSocket?

Tags: c++, qt, networking, qudpsocket

Is there a way I can get the port number the udp socket used to send message?

What I want to do is to send a udp datagram to someone and listen to that sending port.

For example in the following code:

```
QUdpSocket *s = new QUdpSocket(this);
s.writeDataGram(theData,theIp,thePort);
```

does it automaticly binds socket s with whatever the sending port is?

If so, can I listen to that sending port?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be safe to bind the socket to a port, address and specify the [BindMode](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qudpsocket.html#BindFlag-enum) before sending data.

Once a socket is bound to a port and address, [readyRead()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qiodevice.html#readyRead) is emitted upon arrival of `UDP Datagram` at the specified port.

So you can capture the `readyRead()` signal and process the data accordingly, ie you don't need to listen to the port.
If you don't bind the socket `s` to the port `thePort`, `readyRead()` signal won't be emitted  upon arrival of UDP Datagram.

Comment: Binding happens automatically when sending or receiving, unless you have already bound the socket. Your answer therefore doesn't really make sense.

Comment: Hope I answered the listen part atleast.

Answer (score 0):

From the [manual page](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qudpsocket.html#readDatagram) of `readDatagram`:

```
qint64 QUdpSocket::readDatagram ( char * data, qint64 maxSize, QHostAddress * address = 0, quint16 * port = 0 )

Receives a datagram no larger than maxSize bytes and stores it in data.
The sender's host address and port is stored in *address and *port
(unless the pointers are 0).
```

To receive a datagram you must first bind the socket to a specific UDP port. Then to get the source port of received datagrams you supply a non-zero parameter for the `port` argument of `readDatagram`.